# How to call Branch initialisation inside the swift iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, branch, branch.io

- I have an email section inside my ios application and we are receiving links in email messanger, now the problem is when I tap on that link I am not able to get Branch parameters like reference_id, etc... and because of that not able to navigate to specific screens.

In short, we can navigate outside the application using Branch.getInstance().initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions) inside the appdelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method however is it possible to get Branchs params as? [String: AnyObject] inside the application, and yes then how we can access that?*

Answer (score 0):

Could you please recheck on our integration documentation if all the steps have been implemented : https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-basic-integration#section-initialize-branch

Also, check on the Branch SDK integration here : https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-testing#section-test-your-branch-integration

This will help check on the prevalent issue.

If you would need us to check on the integration and the logs, you can reach out to support@branch.io for the same.